# Writing affiliation as a high school student

Tags: affiliation

I want to send an article to a math journal. As with many others, that journal wants a cover letter, which should include the author's affiliation.

I'm still a high school student and my school isn't in the U.S.
How should I write my affiliation?

My school's name is hard to translate to english, should I write its name as in my language? And, when I'm writing my school's adress, should I write it as in my language?

(If you see a grammar mistake and edit it, that would make me really happy.)

Comment: I'd write your school's name and address in _both_ your own language and in English.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, I'm impressed by your ambition here.  And I should warn you not to get discouraged if the math journal ends up rejecting your submission.  Do you have guidance from someone experienced in academic publishing, to help you through the process?

As @Nate-Eldridge pointed out already, you should simply state your affiliation, and the country doesn't matter.  But I will add:

- If the submission is not double-blind, there is a risk that people will take you less seriously when they see the affiliation.  There's not much you can do about this, I think.
- High school students **do** contribute to academic publications, though I was surprised to see this.  One was a coauthor of a paper in a very strong CS systems conference this year (others were at a university).

Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

Simply list your high school as your affiliation, including the city and country where it's located (since there may be many high schools in the world with the same name).

It's irrelevant whether or not it's in the US.

Comment: My school's name is hard to translate to english, should I write its name as in my language? And, when I'm writing my school's adress, should I write it as in my language? Thank you.

Comment: Good question, I am not sure.  Please edit your original question to include that.